# How to get post request using Symfony2

Tags: ajax, json, symfony, xmlhttprequest, base64

For some reason I can't get the post variables from the controller

The AJAX/Javascript

```
function uploadImage(userActionPath,type)
{

    if( (userActionPath == 'undefined') || (type == 'undefined')) {
        console.error("no parameters for function uploadImage defined");
    }

    if((base64code == 'undefined') || (base64code == null))
    {
        console.error("please select an image");
    }

    var xml = ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) ?
            new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    alert(base64code); //<- shows the base64 code, so its there

    var params = userActionPath+"?imagebase64="+base64code+"&type="+type;

    xml.open("POST",userActionPath,true);
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    xml.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if( xml.readyState === 4 && xml.status === 200 )
        {
            var serverResponse = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);

            switch(serverResponse.f)
            {
                case 0:
                    console.log('love sosa'); //<- I get the response
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    xml.send(params);
}
```

The controller

```
class LiveuploadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/LiveUpload",name="fileLiveUpload")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        //I have tried these but 'imagebase64' returns null
        //returns null 
          $value = $request->request->get('imagebase64');
        //returns null
          $value = $request->query->get('imagebase64');
       //returns null 
          $value = $this->get('request')->request->get('imagebase64');

        $response = array('f'=>0,'base64'=>$value);
        return new Response(json_encode($response));
    }
}
```

The request headers also show that the variables are being sent.But both the type AND the imagebase64 variables return null on the controller

Comment: `$value = $request->request->get('imagebase64');` - this should work. You're overwriting `$value` on the next lines.

Comment: I know the value is being overwritten, I'm just showing what I've tried so far, maybe I should write it in a less confusing way

Comment: that one is returning null also, maybe it has something to do with the ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the way that you have setup the XmlHttpRequest.  You have set it up like it should be using `GET`, but when you want to `POST`, it is a bit different.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest) for more info on how to send a `POST` request.  The quick and dirty of it is:

```
var xml = ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) ?
        new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
var params = "imagebase64="+base64code+"&type="+type;
xml.open("POST", userActionPath, true);

xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xml.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xml.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xml.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if( xml.readyState === 4 && xml.status === 200 )
    {
        var serverResponse = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);

        switch(serverResponse.f)
        {
            case 0:
                console.log('love sosa'); //<- I get the response
                break;
        }
    }
};
xml.send(params);
```

In your example code, you are setting the header to expect JSON, but your params are urlencoded.  Setting the proper header should do the trick.

And in your controller, if you are using `POST`, then you should get the request variables like this:

```
// Use this for getting variables of POST requests
$value = $request->request->get('imagebase64');

// This is used for getting variables of GET requests
$value = $request->query->get('imagebase64');
```

Comment: Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length" front:198
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

Comment: but the first one worked, god bless your soul I've been working on this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code in your `JS`:

```
xml.open("POST",userActionPath,true);
```

You are actually supplying `userActionPath` instead of `params` variable. It should be:

```
xml.open("POST",params,true);
```

As for the controller's code you should use:

```
$value = $request->query->get('imagebase64');
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: so then where is the controller path supposed to be passed?
Following this instruction the params should be sent with the send() method 

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: Ahh sorry about that, I missed that. In that case, check you `params` variable - it's value is concatenation of `userActionPath` and your parameters. Try removing `userActionPath` prefix...

Comment: also tried 
$value = $request->get('imagebase64', 'nothing found');
and it returns 'nothing found'

Comment: OK, this proves to be more elusive that I thought :) I assume you have `Firebug` installed. Try firing it up and sending your request again...